# multiple websites getting logged out at same time

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies

I have two different ASP.NET websites hosted on the same machine load balanced. When I have both the websites open in 2 tabs in the same browser and when session times out and logs user out from website 1 user is also immediately logged out from Website 2 even though session hasn't timed out.
Thanks for any help in this regards.

Comment: Are you using the same MachineKey for both applications?

Comment: Webapplication1 uses machinekey and webapplication2 does not have a machinekey specified. The load balancing is happening through sticky cookie.

Comment: WebApplication1 is an MVC application using .NET Framework 4.0 and WebApplication2 is a traditional asp.net website application also using .NET Framework 4.0. Both web applications have separate application pools.